# SQL restore data from transaction log

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a transaction which update data today, but the code used in the transaction have bugs and some of the data updated wrongly.

May i ask if it's possible to restore data by using the transaction log stored in the database?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

using a full back up and a collection of transaction logs you can restore a database to a point in time. If you are looking to not take the database offline to restore, you would need to restore the database to a new database and identify the data that you want to fix and manually "fix" it. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Its very complicated to restore from Tlog,unless you know what you are looking for..use some kind of tool like Apex SQL log (not a freeware) to generate statements from Tlog

You can read more details here

http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx